# How can I insert data from Excel sheet into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have this pretty code for import URL's from Excel and download images to store them in SQL Server in a `varbinary(max)` column.

This code works very well, but I want to store a lot of data like ID, image url, image name besides the binary images.

Can anyone help me with that?

```
// define list of URLs
List<string> imageUrls = new List<string>();

// open Excel file and read in the URLs into a list of strings
string filePath = @"C:\YourUrlDataFile.xlsx";  // adapt to YOUR needs!

// using a "FileStream" and the "ExcelDataReader", read all the URL's
// into a list of strings
using (FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream))
    {
        while (excelReader.Read())
        {
            string url = excelReader.GetString(0);
            imageUrls.Add(url);
        }

        excelReader.Close();
    }
}

// set up the necessary infrastructure for storing into SQL Server
// the query needs to be *ADAPTED* to your own situation - use *YOUR* 
// table and column name!
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.TestImages(ImageData) VALUES(@Image);";

// get the connection string from config - again: *ADAPT* to your situation!
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourDatabase"].ConnectionString;

// use SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using blocks
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    // add parameter to SQL query
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1);

    // loop through the URL's - try to fetch the image, 
    // and if successful, insert into SQL Server database
    foreach (string url in imageUrls)
    {
         try
         {
              // get a new "WebClient", and fetch the data from the URL
              WebClient client = new WebClient();
              byte[] imageData = client.DownloadData(url);

              // open connection
              conn.Open();

              // set the parameter to the data fetched from the URL
              cmd.Parameters["@Image"].Value = imageData;

              // execute SQL query - the return value is the number
              // of rows inserted - should be *1* (if successful)
              int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

              // close connection
              conn.Close();
          }
          catch (Exception exc)
          {
              // Log the exception
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Are these things like ID etc. also stored inside your Excel sheet? What does your target SQL Server table looks like (column names, datatypes)?

Comment: Use the `excelReader.GetString(index);` where `index` is the column to read the data from i think this is what you want

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the problem you can't figure to solve? What have to tried to achieve that or are you asking us to do your work?

Comment: I couldn't do that so I ask to help  do my work !!! 
I put the correct code do you want me put my wrong code here that's what are you mean ؟
I tried 2 days to do that but I failed @ Patrik Eckebrecht

Comment: I just want to know How Can I add one field kind of integer or varchar with the C# code above.
 that's enough to do Add others.

Answer (score 0):

Table SQl server looks like that

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[inv](
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [upc] [bigint] NULL,
    [item_spec] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [quantity] [int] NULL,
    [original_cost] [money] NULL,
    [total_o_cost] [money] NULL,
    [retail_price_usd] [money] NULL,
    [total_o_retail] [money] NULL,
    [vendor_style] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [colors_id] [int] NULL,
    [size_id] [int] NULL,
    [client_cost_usd] [money] NULL,
    [total_client_cost] [money] NULL,
    [div_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [depart_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [vendor_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [image] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [image_id] [int] NULL,
    [location_id] [int] NULL,
    [id_lot_number] [int] NULL,
    [lot_number] [int] NULL,
    [bol] [float] NULL,
    [categories_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [return_id] [int] NULL,
    [of_pallets] [float] NULL,
    [of_cartons] [float] NULL,
    [season_id] [int] NULL,
    [hs_code] [int] NULL,
    [sales_price] [money] NULL,
    [brand_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sku] [int] NULL,
    [barcode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [sar] [money] NULL,
    [aed] [money] NULL,
    [bhd] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_inv] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```